Applink is not working when app is not installed on the device in react native
useEffect(() => {
Linking.addEventListener('url', evt => {
console.log('URL:', evt.url);
handleAppLink(evt.url);
});
return () => {
  Linking.removeAllListeners('url');
};

}, [handleAppLink]);
// handles deep link when app is not already opened
useEffect(() => {
const getInitialUrlAsync = async () => {
const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
if (url) {
console.log('Initial URL:', url);
handleAppLink(url);
}
};
getInitialUrlAsync();
}, [handleAppLink]);
also this
// UPDATES AUTH INITIAL URL FROM APP LINK WITH CODE
useEffect(() => {
if (appLink && appLink.includes('/signUp/')) {
const code = appLink
.substring(appLink.indexOf('/signUp/') + '/signUp/'.length)
.split('/')[0];
setSignUpCode(code);
setAuthInitialRoute('SignUp');
setIsLoading(false);
}
}, [appLink, setAuthInitialRoute, setIsLoading, setSignUpCode]);

If you are using Branch SDK for deep linking, then you have to use the Branch subscription listener function. I suggest to refer the below link for reference.

https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native-basic-integration
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native-advanced-features


Yes, already did the code for this.
